# You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your android project by calling firebase.storage()

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

Im trying to use firebase storage on React Native using the react-native-firebase module and when y call firebase storage I get this error:

[You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your android project by calling firebase.storage()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yk1yS.png)2IM.png

I have add all the necessary dependancies already.

**android/app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.detecta.detecta"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.1.6"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + 
defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-image-crop-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-svg')
    compile(project(':react-native-firebase')) {
        transitive = false
    }
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0"
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**MainApplication.java**

```
package com.detecta;

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.BuildConfig;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import io.invertase.firebase.RNFirebasePackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.auth.RNFirebaseAuthPackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.database.RNFirebaseDatabasePackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.storage.RNFirebaseStoragePackage;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
              new MainReactPackage(),
              new RNFirebasePackage(),
              new RNFirebaseAuthPackage(),
              new RNFirebaseDatabasePackage(),
              new RNFirebaseStoragePackage()
      );
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

Calling the method

```
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

/*...*/

uploadImage(userId) {
    path = this.state.image ? this.state.image.uri : null;
    firebase
        .storage()
        .ref(`users/${userId}/profile.jpg`)
        .putFile(path)
        .then(snapshot => {
            console.log(snapshot)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        });
};
```

Comment: did you rebuild your app after adding these (not just restarting the packager)?

Comment: yes I clean and rebuild the app with android studio.

Comment: @ItaloFernándezSalgado Have you been able to fix it? I'm running into the same issue! Appreciate your help.. thanks

Comment: @Mutaz Sorry was not use firebase storage. I save the profile image as an string on firebase database as a work around.

Comment: I am getting this problem for firebase invites

Answer (score 8):

I had this issue:

> you attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling `firebase.app()`

In the end I figured out the issue; I was using 'Expo Start' to run my project and `firebase.app()` isn't supported by expo for some reason.
It worked by using `expo run:android`.

I couldn't find the solution anywhere else, so I made an account just for this.

Comment: Here is a relevant link: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-firebase/#usage-with-expo=

Answer (score 7):

Add to the import section of the app **MainApplication** class the following:

```html
import io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingPackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseNotificationsPackage;
```

Add to packages loop the following:

```html
 protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          ...
         packages.add(new RNFirebaseMessagingPackage());
         packages.add(new RNFirebaseNotificationsPackage());
         return packages;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the `npx expo run:android` command and it is running, but when you try to run the expo server using the `npx expo start` command, and it is not running, then the problem is related to expo/firebase inconsistency.
Install two things for your project:

1. npx expo install expo-dev-client
2. npx expo install @react-native-firebase/app

You can follow this instruction's second choice:

https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-firebase/#usage-with-expo=

Then, it will work with both commands.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also experiencing the same issue when trying to use firebase.messaging() with Expo dev builds and Android emulators. iOS works correctly however.

If i remove the app from the Android emulator and reinstall the APK build from Expo Builds then the app runs correctly. However as soon as I restart the emulator I get this issue again, and have to remove and reinstall the app on the emulator.

For now I'm having to do the above as a workaround.

```
ERROR  Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.messaging().

Ensure you have:

1) imported the 'io.invertase.firebase.messaging.ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingPackage' module in your 'MainApplication.java' file.

2) Added the 'new ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingPackage()' line inside of the RN 'getPackages()' method list.

See http://invertase.link/android for full setup instructions.
```

```
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.8.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^18.8.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^18.8.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^18.8.0",
    "expo": "~50.0.5",
    "expo-router": "~3.4.6"
```

```
  expo-env-info 1.2.0 environment info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 13.6.3
      Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
    Binaries:
      Node: 18.16.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.22.17 - /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
      npm: 9.5.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/bin/npm
      Watchman: 2023.02.27.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
    Managers:
      CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /opt/homebrew/bin/pod
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: DriverKit 23.2, iOS 17.2, macOS 14.2, tvOS 17.2, visionOS 1.0, watchOS 10.2
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 2023.1 AI-231.9392.1.2311.11330709
      Xcode: 15.2/15C500b - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      expo: ~50.0.5 => 50.0.7 
      expo-router: ~3.4.6 => 3.4.7 
      react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0 
      react-dom: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0 
      react-native: 0.73.2 => 0.73.2 
      react-native-web: ~0.19.6 => 0.19.10 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      eas-cli: 7.3.0
      expo-cli: 6.3.10
    Expo Workflow: bare
```

[image: Emulator error]

Answer (score 0):

In August, 2022; Just rebuild the project with `npx react-native run-android`, and it will do the trick.

Answer (score -2):

**The same error are occur for me but solve by the following way........**

[image]**

I have changed some files, and it should work properly for me.

**My MainApplication.java code here...**

```
package com.scllogin;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

// import co.apptailor.googlesignin.RNGoogleSigninPackage;

import io.invertase.firebase.RNFirebasePackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.auth.RNFirebaseAuthPackage;


import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.hermes.reactexecutor.HermesExecutorFactory;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptExecutorFactory;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBSDKPackage;
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
       @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      // new RNFirebaseNotificationsPackage();
      // new MainReactPackage();
      // new RNFirebasePackage();
      // new RNGoogleSigninPackage();
      // new RNFirebaseAuthPackage();
      packages.add(new RNFirebaseAuthPackage());
      // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
      // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
      return packages;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

**And my android/app/build.gradle file are**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
 *   bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and mirrored here.  If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.scllogin"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst '**/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/x86/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/x86/libjsc.so'
        pickFirst '**/armeabi-v7a/libjsc.so'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-fbsdk')

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0"
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9"

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.2"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth"
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    if (enableHermes) {
      def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermesvm/android/";
      debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
      releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
      implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**And my android/build.gradle file are..**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**And My App.js file are as...**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Button, Text, TextInput, Image } from 'react-native';

import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

const successImageUri = 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/06/09/16/12/icon-803718_1280.png';

export default class MobileLoginScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.unsubscribe = null;
    this.state = {
      user: null,
      message: '',
      codeInput: '',
      phoneNumber: '+91',
      confirmResult: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.setState({ user: user.toJSON() });
      } else {
        // User has been signed out, reset the state
        this.setState({
          user: null,
          message: '',
          codeInput: '',
          phoneNumber: '+91',
          confirmResult: null,
        });
      }
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
     if (this.unsubscribe) this.unsubscribe();
  }

  signIn = () => {
    const { phoneNumber } = this.state;
    this.setState({ message: 'Sending code ...' });

    firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
      .then(confirmResult => this.setState({ confirmResult, message: 'Code has been sent!' }))
      .catch(error => this.setState({ message: `Sign In With Phone Number Error: ${error.message}` }));
  };

  confirmCode = () => {
    const { codeInput, confirmResult } = this.state;

    if (confirmResult && codeInput.length) {
      confirmResult.confirm(codeInput)
        .then((user) => {
          this.setState({ message: 'Code Confirmed!' });
        })
        .catch(error => this.setState({ message: `Code Confirm Error: ${error.message}` }));
    }
  };

  signOut = () => {
    firebase.auth().signOut();
  }

  renderPhoneNumberInput() {
   const { phoneNumber } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={{ padding: 25 }}>
        <Text>Enter phone number:</Text>
        <TextInput
          autoFocus
          style={{ height: 40, marginTop: 15, marginBottom: 15 }}
          onChangeText={value => this.setState({ phoneNumber: value })}
          placeholder={'Phone number ... '}
          value={phoneNumber}
        />
        <Button title="Sign In" color="green" onPress={this.signIn} />
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderMessage() {
    const { message } = this.state;

    if (!message.length) return null;

    return (
      <Text style={{ padding: 5, backgroundColor: '#000', color: '#fff' }}>{message}</Text>
    );
  }

  renderVerificationCodeInput() {
    const { codeInput } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={{ marginTop: 25, padding: 25 }}>
        <Text>Enter verification code below:</Text>
        <TextInput
          autoFocus
          style={{ height: 40, marginTop: 15, marginBottom: 15 }}
          onChangeText={value => this.setState({ codeInput: value })}
          placeholder={'Code ... '}
          value={codeInput}
        />
        <Button title="Confirm Code" color="#841584" onPress={this.confirmCode} />
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { user, confirmResult } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>

        {!user && !confirmResult && this.renderPhoneNumberInput()}

        {this.renderMessage()}

        {!user && confirmResult && this.renderVerificationCodeInput()}

        {user && (
          <View
            style={{
              padding: 15,
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
              backgroundColor: '#77dd77',
              flex: 1,
            }}
          >
            <Image source={{ uri: successImageUri }} style={{ width: 100, height: 100, marginBottom: 25 }} />
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 25 }}>Signed In!</Text>
            <Text>{JSON.stringify(user)}</Text>
            <Button title="Sign Out" color="red" onPress={this.signOut} />
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**Also you can follow these link for the mobile authentication using firebase.**

https://aboutreact.com/example-of-google-sign-in-in-react-native/

https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/auth/phone-auth..

these link are working for me..

Comment: This is a very vague answer, please specify which part of the file made it work for you? And what was the issue to begin with?

Comment: This not an appropriate answer, it does not explain anything, just a large puch of line codes

Comment: Such a loooong comment! :S i need some help on this