# React Native Error: Attempted to use a firebase module that is not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.firestore()

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am not sure what else to do. I have this erros when trying to login into a application:

React Native Error: Attempted to use a firebase module that is not installed on your Andrid project by calling firebase.firestore()

I read documentation and everything looks good according to it.

MainApplication.java:

```
>     import io.invertase.firebase.auth.RNFirebaseAuthPackage;
>     import io.invertase.firebase.RNFirebasePackage;
>     import io.invertase.firebase.storage.RNFirebaseStoragePackage;
>     import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
      // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
      packages.add(new RNFirebaseAuthPackage());
      packages.add(new RNFirebaseStoragePackage());
      return packages;
    }
```

build.gradle in android/:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1")
```

build.gradle in android/app

```
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.2.1"
```

Already clean e nothing works. I still getting the same error. According to the documentation, all the files are right configured.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your android project by calling firebase.storage()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48841648/you-attempted-to-use-a-firebase-module-thats-not-installed-on-your-android-proj)

Comment: This might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48841648/you-attempted-to-use-a-firebase-module-thats-not-installed-on-your-android-proj