# firebase createUserWithEmailAndPassword() undefined error, even after it shows account is created on firebase console

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication

when the handlesignup function is called, it gives and error undefined. but it shows user details when `console.log("user mail at signup", user);` , previously it worked fine.I cannot find a solution for this.

I already commented out codelines below the `console.log("user mail at signup", user);` but still error occurs.

```
const handleSignUp = async () => {
    try {
      if (macAdd.length !== 12) {
        Alert.alert(t("signupFailed"), t("shortMacAdd"));
        return;
      }

      const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        email,
        password
      );

      const user = userCredential.user;
      console.log("user mail at signup", user);
      await updateProfile(user, { displayName: macAdd });

      const token = await messaging().getToken();
      const dataRef = ref(database, macAdd + "/");
      await update(dataRef, { FCM_token: token });
      console.log("FCM_token", token);

      setIsDialog1Visible(true);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Error signing up:", err.code);
      if (err.code === "auth/email-already-in-use") {
        Alert.alert(t("signupFailed"), t("auth/email-already-in-useBody"));
      } else if (err.code === "auth/invalid-email") {
        Alert.alert(t("signupFailed"), t("auth/invalid-emailBody"));
      } else if (err.code === "auth/weak-password") {
        Alert.alert(t("signupFailed"), t("auth/weak-passwordBody"));
      } else if (err.code === "auth/missing-password") {
        Alert.alert(t("signupFailed"), t("auth/missing-passwordBody"));
      } else {
        Alert.alert(t("signupFailed"), t("otherErrorSignup"));
      }
    }
  };
```

it gives and error undefined

---

This is the `err.message` I previously printed err.code

> Error signing up: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.app().  Ensure you have:  1) imported the 'io.invertase.firebase.app.ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage' module in your 'MainApplication.java' file.  2) Added the 'new ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage()' line inside of the RN 'getPackages()' method list.

Comment: ```Error signing up: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.app().

Ensure you have:

1) imported the 'io.invertase.firebase.app.ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage' module in your 'MainApplication.java' file.

2) Added the 'new ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage()' line inside of the RN 'getPackages()' method list. ```

this is the err.message ; previously i printed err.code

Comment: sounds like your project doesn't recognise firebase probably an issue with package installation run this                                                                           
./gradlew clean build (Mac and Linux) 

gradlew clean build (Windows)                                                                                
or you can check out this topic  :: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48841648/you-attempted-to-use-a-firebase-module-thats-not-installed-on-your-android-proj