# You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.app() by calling expo start

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

In my react-native expo project, I am using Firebase and Firestore packages, After the splash screen I am getting this error:

> You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.app(). imported the import io.invertase.firebase.app.ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage

I am using the following versions.

```
"expo": "^50.0.0",
"react-native": "0.73.5",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.5.0",
"@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^18.5.0",
```

I have added `import io.invertase.firebase.app.ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage;` in mainapplication.java file.

`implementation project(':@react-native-firebase_firestore')` in android/app/build.gradle

Whenever I am doing the "expo start" command I get above error after the splash screen in android.

How to fix this? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You be trying to use a firebase module that's not installed on ur Android project by calling firebase.app(). then need to be importing the import io.invertase.firebase.app.ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage. Make sure add this package to ur Android project's dependencies, or else you'll be running into errors, mate!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your android project by calling firebase.storage()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48841648/you-attempted-to-use-a-firebase-module-thats-not-installed-on-your-android-proj)